# Uncaught typeerror.. is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't figure out why this keeps giving me an anonymous function error and won't run properly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '.mobile-menu', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

The error:

> Uncaught typeerror.. is not a function

Comment: It looks good, it should work. Have you included jQuery library?

Comment: Could you tell me what `console.log(window.$)` returns?

Comment: Try to test, if jQuery is loaded. console.log(jQuery)

Comment: console.log(window.$) returns: 
(a,b){return new c.fn.init(a,b)} on VM68261:2
undefined

Comment: wrap your codes in document ready: `$( document ).ready(function() {});`

Comment: @deepakb I did that just now and it didn't seem to solve the problem. Thanks though!

Comment: @Carmen It shouldn't fix anything here, eventually: `$( document ).ready(function($) {})` but not `$( document ).ready(function() {})`. It just looks like `$` isn't refering to jQuery in your code

Comment: @jacquesmarais Does this mean that jquery has loaded? I went ahead and added another source for jquery (google content delivery network) and still same error.

Comment: Try this: `if (window.jQuery) {  // jQuery is loaded } else {// jQuery is not loaded};` and verify jQuery is loaded or not!

Comment: @deepakb Jquery is indeed loaded. I should also mention that I have other jquery statements that aren't giving me an anonymous function error, just this one!

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/JacquesMarais/ea7vq7x7/

Comment: what is the jQuery version?

Answer (score 0):

When using a code similar to the below:

```
AUI().use('aui-io-request', function(A){}
```

The browser's console will throw this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: "io.upload is not a function"
```

**Solution :**

Add `io` to the `aui:script` tag's dependency list, as below:

```
AUI().use('aui-base', 'io', 'aui-io-request', function(A){}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to do something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.mobile-menu').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This won't change anything, the code the OP described is valid if jQuery is loaded